# Is the series $a_n = (1 + (-1)^{n}3)^{-n} n^{2}$ absolutely convergent$?$

Tags: sequences-and-series

The given series is $a_n = (1 + (-1)^{n}3)^{-n} n^2$

I need to check if it is absolutely convergent.

I partition the standard form of series to get -
$$a_n = \frac{n^{2}}{(-2)^{n}} = \frac{(-1)^{n}n^{2}}{2^n}  $$, when $n$ is odd

And

$$a_n = \frac{n^{2}}{4^{n}},$$ when n is even.

Since, both parts are absolutely convergent, can I conclude from this that the whole series is absolutely convergent$?$

Moreover, Is this series  an alternating series ?

The series is changing its sign alternatively, but it's not in the form of $\sum (-1)^{n}a_n$

Answer (score 2):

From what you have found you can say that $$|a_n|\leq \frac{n^2}{2^n}$$
for all $n$. Since by ratio test $\sum \frac{n^2}{2^n}$ converges, hence $\sum |a_n|$ converges, i.e. $\sum a_n$ is absolutely convergent.

Answer (score 0):

You can first use absolute convergence, remember the (reverse) triangle inequality and notice that $n^2/3^n \leq 1/2^n$ from some $n$ (now by comparison with a geometric series you can conclude)